# Summarize the cost by groups in org table

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Suppose such a spreadsheet in org table

```
|------------+-------+------------+--------+--------+------------|
| Date       | Items | Unit Price | Amount | Amount | Categories |
|------------+-------+------------+--------+--------+------------|
| 2019/09/17 | A     |       2.64 |      1 |   2.64 | materials  |
|            | B     |      52.67 |      2 | 105.34 | diagnosis  |
|            | C     |       3.08 |      1 |   3.08 | materials  |
|            | D     |       3.85 |      2 |    7.7 | materials  |
|            | E     |      33.66 |      2 |  67.32 | materials  |
|            | F     |         40 |      1 |     40 | treatments |
|            | G     |       16.5 |      1 |   16.5 | materials  |
|            | H     |          4 |      3 |     12 | treatments |
|            | I     |         40 |      1 |     40 | bed        |
| x          | M     |       6    |     13 |     78 | treatments |
|------------+-------+------------+--------+--------+------------|
#+TBLFM: $5=$3*$4
```

I want to sum up the material fees.

Is it possible to calculate it by grouping like `vsum(where Categories == materials)`?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this with an elisp expression will be:

```
|------------+-------+------------+--------+--------+------------|
| Date       | Items | Unit Price | Amount | Amount | Categories |
|------------+-------+------------+--------+--------+------------|
| 2019/09/17 | A     |       2.64 |      1 |   2.64 | materials  |
|            | B     |      52.67 |      2 | 105.34 | diagnosis  |
|            | C     |       3.08 |      1 |   3.08 | materials  |
|            | D     |       3.85 |      2 |    7.7 | materials  |
|            | E     |      33.66 |      2 |  67.32 | materials  |
|            | F     |         40 |      1 |     40 | treatments |
|            | G     |       16.5 |      1 |   16.5 | materials  |
|            | H     |          4 |      3 |     12 | treatments |
|            | I     |         40 |      1 |     40 | bed        |
| x          | M     |          6 |     13 |     78 | treatments |
|------------+-------+------------+--------+--------+------------|
| TOTAL:     |       |            |        |  97.24 |            |
|------------+-------+------------+--------+--------+------------|
#+TBLFM: $5=$3*$4
#+TBLFM: @12$5='(apply #'+ (cl-mapcar (lambda (num category) (if (eq category 'materials) num 0)) '(@II$5..@III$5) '(@II$6..@III$6)));L
```

`cl-mapcar` applies `+` to cell @12$5 by comparing the list which is column 6 to symbol`'materials`.

This solution and a `calc solution in [emacsSE](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/33571/17548)

Comment: One nit: use @> instead of @12 to refer to the last row - it's easier than having to count rows or using `C-c ?` to get coordinates and more importantly  it's easier on the reader. Also @>> is the second-to-last row etc. Similarly for columns: $> is the last column. See the [References](https://orgmode.org/manual/References.html#References) section in the manual.